# How to get another field of same object in JSON with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, search

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
 {
  "title": "film1",
  "actor": ["jack", "fred"]
 },
 {
   "title": "film2",
   "actor": ["jack", "tom"]
 },
 {
  "title": "film3",
  "actor": ["albert", "luke"]
 }
]
```

There is an input element where the user can search inside this JSON.
When the user type a string, the app should return a list of the corresponding "*title*" fields.

Example:
The user types "**jack**". The app should return:

```
- film1
- film2
```

Because the string "jack" is only in the "*actor*" array of **film1** and **film2**.

How do I code this? I think I should use Object.values and Array.prototype.reduce() but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using JavaScript array methods**

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for a one line solution. To make the search case-insensitive we also need to convert both the keyword and the actor name to uppercase before doing the compare.

```
films.filter(p => p.actor.some(name => name.toUpperCase() === keyword)).map(p => p.title);
```

**Run the snippet to understand how it works**

```js
let films = [
 {
  "title": "film1",
  "actor": ["jack", "fred"]
 },
 {
   "title": "film2",
   "actor": ["jack", "tom"]
 },
 {
  "title": "film3",
  "actor": ["albert", "luke"]
 }
];


search.onchange = function(e) {

  let keyword = (search.value || "").trim().toUpperCase();
  
  let result =  films.filter(p => p.actor.some(name => name.toUpperCase() === keyword)).map(p => p.title);
  
  if (!result.length) result.push("No matches");
  
  output.innerHTML = "<li>" + result.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
  
}

search.onchange();
```

```html
<p>Enter a keyword and press enter:</p>
<input id="search" type="text" value="Jack">

<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var actor = "jack";
var films = [];
actors.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.actor.includes(actor)) films.push(item.title);
});
console.log(films);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with Yogi's answer